# Google Search Queries Periodically Timeout

Tags: networking, dns, google-search

We are experiencing intermittent timeouts (Chrome error: ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT) and/or significantly delayed queries when attempting to search Google.com. When using Firefox, when the issue is occurring, it will attempt to load our search and after a while (10+ seconds), times-out without any visible error. It only seems to effect Google search queries and no other domains. My end users are hardwired (CAT 5/6) on up-to-date Windows 10 OS's. This is affecting most (*if not all*) of my users, which leads me to believe that the issue is not related to the user's web browser or client. This happens all throughout the day and is not consolidated to a certain time. It does not appear to only be occurring during abnormally high network volume. This issue appears to have started around 10/17/2022. No significant network modifications had occurred prior to us experiencing this issue. All except one of my users are on site and the one off-site user uses our L2TP vpn that is provided by our router (Synology RT2600ac).

**What I have tried**:

• Restarted network equipment (router/modem)
• Restarted end user's PC
• Restarted user's desktop switch (if applicable)
• Restarted end user's VOIP phone (pass-through device)
• Cleared all browser caches
• Disabled browser extensions
• Scanned for malware
• Flushed DNS (ipconfig /flushdns)
• Disabled security software/firewall
• Disabled/Enabled IPv6
• Changed our DNS from Comcast (75.75.75.75, 75.75.75.76) to Google (8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4) on the gateway. All of my users obtain their DNS from the gateway. Attempted forcing users to obtain manual dns from Google, which appears to have at least helped.
• ipconfig /flushdns
• ipconfig /registerdns
• ipconfig /release
• ipconfig /renew
• netsh winsock reset
• nbtstat -R (administrator)
• Unregistered domain’s service workers (about:serviceworkers)
• Disabling ‘DoS Protection’ on the router doesn’t seem to help.
• Disabling ‘IPv6’ on the router doesn’t seem to help.
• Disabled ‘Threat Intelligence database’ on the gateway.
• SSL/HTTP IN & Out doesn’t seem to have any effect.

**What I intend to try** during off hours (as it may effect reliability/up time):

• Switch our other provider's modem
• Switch to our spare router
• Factory reset / restore to earlier version our main Synology router
• Disable Smart WAN & Interface 2
• Try a long modem/router power down
• Replace cable from modem to router
• Disable VPN/DNS rules on the Gateway Firewall.
• Disable DNS Server/Resolution service on gateway
• Disabling DNS Resolution services on the gateway disabled internet access for mobile devices at least.
• Third party service VPN to establish another route

At this point, I'm fairly sure it's a network-wide issue, either relating to the router or service provider. On our router, we have a DNS server running which I'm not sure what it's being used for, because I'm telling my clients to obtain a static DNS (that I enter) from either Google or our ISP. This could potentially be the issue, however after I disabled DNS resolution from that software, some of my users were unable to resolve domains.

[image: Synology Router DNS Server]

Does anybody have any other recommendations?

Comment: Does it happen if you connect to a phone's hotspot? Have you contacted the ISP or tried another one?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Harry. 

We don't have a hotspot on site, however I do intend on trying our secondary ISP, probably this weekend. Our primary ISP said it was a browser issue, localized to each individual workstation and wiped their hands clean of it after doing a traceroute from our modem.

Comment: Suggestion: Download `mtr` and run it against any larger server out in the dark. This might though have the effect of keeping the connection(s) up constantly. Which then might indicate some kind of "power saving" -mode being active somewhere (in the router?).